# MySQL table to column list query

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to workout how to query the table I have and produce a specific output format in my select statement. The source table data is as follows

```
+-----------+------------------------+
| prefix_id | Description  | A  | B  |
+-----------+------------------------+
|     55207 | TEST 1       | 1  | 0  |
|     55363 | Test 2       | 1  | 0  |
|     55378 | Test 3       | 0  | 1  |
|     55379 | Test 4       | 1  | 1  |
+-----------+------------------------+
```

The output I desire for the above data is as follows

```
+-----------+------------+
| A         | B          |
+-----------+------------|
| TEST 1    | Test 3     |
| Test 2    | Test 4     |
| Test 4    | NULL       |
+-----------+------------+
```

As you can see Test 4 description appears twice as it is true for column A and B but the order is unimportant. NULL characters should only appear at the end of the column A or B. The IDs are not important as long as each entry appears once under the corresponding columns.

Maybe a temporary table will help but I can't figure out how. The separate queries for column A or B are easy but it is merging them together into the output is my problem.

Imagine the output as being something you see in excel, you want the data at the top of the column filled out with blanks at the bottom

Your help is much appreciated.

Note. Looking to achieve this in an sql query. The query output gets rendered using something called myDBR an Analytics reporting tool.

Comment: A columns A and B expressing some sort of relationship?

Comment: Extending Mike's comment, is there a reason why test3 appears alongside test1 as opposed to test2?

Comment: There is no relationship between columns A and B. Column A is all descriptions where A s true and column is All the descriptions where column B is true. It is like trying yo get two separate lists out in one sql query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in SQL.  What you are trying to do is align two lists -- fortunately, you don't care about the order (because you have no column to specify ordering).

The following breaks the data in two pieces, one for the "A" column and one for the "B" column.  It then uses a MySQL trick to calculate a sequential number (other databases would use `row_number()` for this).

Here is the query:

```
select MAX(A), MAX(B)
from ((select @rn1 := @rn1 + 1 as rn, Description as A, NULL as B
       from t cross join (select @rn1 := 0) const
       where A = 1
      ) union all
      (select @rn2 := @rn2 + 1 as rn, NULL as A, Description as B
       from t cross join (select @rn2 := 0) const
       where B = 1
      )
     ) t
group by rn
```

Comment: looks promising...I'll try to apply this to my real world scenario

Answer (score 0):

A simple database query can grab all results. Loop through them to determine whether they belong in column A, or B, or both.

```
<?php
// Query all entries from database
$rs = mysql_query('SELECT Description, A, B FROM table ORDER BY Description ASC');

// Loop through all rows in result set
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $rs ) ){
    // if Column A = 1, add to $colA array
    if ( $row['A'] > 0 ) $colA[] = $row;
    // if Column B = 1, add to $colB array
    if ( $row['B'] > 0 ) $colB[] = $row;
}
```

Now you need to do something with the data. Hard to tell from your question if you want it displayed in HTML format, or dumped into CSV format, or something else.

But, you now have array $colA that contains rows matching A=1, and array $colB that contains rows matching B=1.

Here's an approach to output in HTML:

```
<?php

// Setup the base table
$table_html = '<table><tr><th>A</th><th>B</th></tr>';
$x=0;


// Determine which array has more children
if ( count( $colA ) >= count( $colB ) ) {
    $use = 'colA'; // A has more
    $counter = 'colB';
} else {
    $use = 'colB'; // B has more
    $counter = 'colA';
}

// The variable variable lets us use either $colA or $colB, as determined by the value in $use.
// More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php
foreach ( $$use as $row ){
    // Append the current row, and if its counterpart exists, the other row

    if ( $use == 'colA' ){
        $table_html .= '<tr><td>' . $row['Description'] . '</td><td>' . ( isset( ${$counter}[ $x ] ) ? ${$counter}[ $x ]['Description'] : '' ) . '</td></tr>';
    } else {
        $table_html .= '<tr><td>' . ( isset( ${$counter}[ $x ] ) ? ${$counter}[ $x ]['Description'] : '' ) . '</td><td>' . $row['Description'] . '</td></tr>';
    }
    $x++; // Increment the counter
}

// Close the table
$table_html .= '</table>';

// Output to browser
echo $table_html;
```

Comment: Perhaps I should have added that I was trying to do this in an sql query